# Adobe Illustrator: Extract mesh faces from Blender Freestyle SVG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blender

I've created this very simple model in Blender using [Freestyle Linesets](https://youtu.be/_aTCMWnJKpE). I've exported it as SVG using the [Freestyle SVG Exporter](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/render_freestyle_svg.html). Now, I try to color some of the faces in Adobe Illustrator CC.

[image: OLAP Data Cube Slicing]

The path consists of tons of anchor points as can be seen here:
[image: path with lots of points]

So, I've used `Object -> Path -> Simplify`. I thought I could easily go ahead and color the faces. However, there's still one problem:

[image]

There's not just one closed path for every face. When I drag the paths apart a little, you can see where they actually go and that oftentimes multiple anchor-points lie exactly on top of each other. I've tried to join, but this only works for the start/end of a path.

Is there any easy way to get the paths to form individual faces (rectangular shapes), so that I could color them individually? Of course, for this simple shape, I could redraw the faces with the pencil tool. I'm just wondering if there's a more elegant solution to this...

*Note that - to my knowledge - Blender Freestyles don't support coloring faces when we still want to export as SVG, that's why I try to do the coloring in Illustrator in the first place.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After* simplifying, Select All and then use the **Live Paint Bucket Tool** to click each face and fill it with a color, any color.

After you've clicked all the faces, *expand* the Live Paint Object (via the button at the top of the screen). This will result in a shape for each face rather than merely strokes defining faces.

- You can also probably use the **Shape Builder Tool** in a similar fashion, without color. I'm uncertain if Shape Builder will result in a collection of shapes easily the way the Live Paint Bucket Tool will. Theoretically it *should*, but this depends much on the artwork.
- The **Pathfinder Panel** operations *may* also assist, specifically the `Merge` operation. However, this again depends upon the actual construction. Pathfinder doesn't like strokes for many operations. So my initial impression is Pathfinder may *not* suffice. I post this because it *will* work for *some* artwork.

Comment: Thank you ;) The Live Paint Bucket Tool in combination with `expand` is exactly what I was looking for. The "Shape Builder Tool" also worked, but like you said, it won't generate faces separate from the strokes. So I like the Live Paint Bucket Tool more for this.

Comment: Glad that worked for you `:)`